# How to dynamically use a Vuetify component in vue-cli project

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm experiencing a problem in my vue-cli created application. The following does not work:

```
<component :is="'v-text-field'"></component>
```

However a simple `<v-text-field />` works great

The error is:

```
Unknown custom element: <v-text-field> - did you register the component correctly?
```

**Does someone knows why? I can't reproduce it on codepen**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you using `vuetify-loader` with tree-shaking? If so, you may just want to `import {VTextField} from 'vuetify/lib'` and add `components: { VTextField }`

Comment: Is there a way to make all components available? Especially the ones already in use?